# How to get MS Access to group by date column

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, jet-sql

I'm having difficulty grouping by date in Microsoft Access. Any guidance would be great. Thank you.

Fake Table - schedules:

| Date | Location | Appointment ID | People |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/23 | East | 98765 | 3 |
| 1/4/23 | West | 983746 | 2 |
| 1/3/23 | East | 09382 | 5 |

Query I'm using:

```
SELECT schedules.Date, schedules.Location, COUNT(schedules.[Appointment ID]) AS [Appointment Count], SUM(schedules.[People]) AS [People Served]
FROM schedules
GROUP BY schedules.Date, schedules.Location;
```

I'd like the following table:

| Date | Location | Appointment Count | People Served |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/23 | East | 2 | 8 |
| 1/4/23 | West | 1 | 2 |

BUT my code won't allow grouping on the date for whatever reason. It's a short date without the time. With my code, the first table is returned back to me. If I omit the date, it will group by location.

Comment: Field is formatted to display as Short Date, however, time component could still be in the actual value. Format property does not alter data. Remove the format from field in table and see what values show. Grouping by date works for me. Date is a reserved word. Would be better not to use reserved words as names. Also, advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: @June7 Thanks! I'll remove the formatting. It's not actually named 'Date', just used that here for an example. I agree with the naming convention unfortunately my boss does not. thx

Comment: Why does boss care about field names? You make labels show whatever you want.

Comment: @June7 I was under the impression that the columns in the access database have to match exactly to new excel files that are coming in otherwise they won't import correctly.

Comment: You didn't mention before that data was Excel import. However, Format setting should not have anything to do with import process.

Answer (score 1):

Base your groups on `DateValue(<your Date/Time field>)` to group all records from the same day together regardless of their time component.

```sql
SELECT
    DateValue(s.Date),
    s.Location,
    COUNT(s.[Appointment ID]) AS [Appointment Count],
    SUM(s.[People]) AS [People Served]
FROM schedules AS s
GROUP BY DateValue(s.Date), s.Location;
```